# Left Join Statement returns multiple rows instead of one

Tags: mysql, join, query

There are two tables, namely `sku` and `country` without any matching columns. I need to retrieve a unique field `printable_name` from country table based on the value of `c_code` in `sku` table. The result from my SQL statement below gives multiple rows instead of just one. I just want the record only from country table.

I am trying to combine the following SQLs into one with the JOIN statement so that I get country name with a single SQL statement.

```
$vendor_sku = $my_line_item['sku'];
                    
                    // Build SQL to retrieve country name.
                    $sql = "SELECT c_code FROM sku WHERE item_sku = '" . $vendor_sku . "'";
                    $sql = "SELECT printable_name FROM country WHERE numcode = '" . $c_code . "'";

SELECT country.printable_name
  FROM country INNER JOIN sku ON country.numcode = sku.c_code
 WHERE country.numcode = "124"
```

part of country table is:

[image]

part of sku table is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, it's so that we can easily copy and paste to test ourselves. Please edit your question and provide a complete working example (create table, insert data, and any queries you've tried yourself).

Comment: All the above tables are created in a db called poms. The query I tried is also written in the post above.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk, choose your version of MySQL and put in some table DDL, and insert some records and give us your desired result as determined by the fiddle...

Comment: Why does `sku` table even needs to be accessed? Why not just `SELECT printable_name FROM country WHERE numcode = '124' ;`

Comment: @CodeForGood - please look at [mcve] for details about how to provide a good-quality question.  Also, as previously mentioned, please only post the text of the command, not a screenshot.  i.e. copy-and-paste the query text from your editor into the question body, and use code formatting around it, as detailed in [mcve].  Also, adding pictures of the data helps no-one since we cannot easily recreate your scenario.  Add nicely-formatted tables to your question with sample data, and desired output.

Comment: The Title talks about `LEFT JOIN`, yet the question shows only `INNER JOIN`.  I would expect the given `SELECT` to list all the Canadian items, not just one.  Your snippet of `sku` shows that there are several items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say there are no matching rows between the two tables, you cannot retrive a unique value from country table based on sku.numcode. You need to add a foreign key on sku table which matches the country table, using some unique value ( perhaps iso or numcode, better if it's the int field numcode, but this needs to be unique in this table ).

If there's an error in your explanation, and sku.c_code matches country.numcode, you can do:

select c.printable_name from country c inner join sku s on c.numcode = s.c_code where s.c_code = '124' limit 1;

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but please understand sku table has c_code field while country has numcode field. numcode of country table is unique while c_code of sku table is not. Both these columns carry the same data, but c_code contains them multiple times while numcode only once.

Comment: I've updated my answer assuming your question was not accurate, and c.numcode and s.c_code are the matching columns.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. c.numcode and s.c_code are the matching columns.

Comment: I don't want to use limit because country has only one rowfor that numcode value 124. Added a image to the post. Please see

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Still wondering if there is simpler way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is incomplete. Try this:

```
SELECT country.printable_name
  FROM country INNER JOIN sku ON country.numcode = sku.c_code
 WHERE country.numcode = "124"
```

Without this, the database engine doesn't know how to join `country` with `sku` and will quite literally join each record with everything, resulting in a lot of "bad" data.

Comment: Thanks, but your SQL returns `Showing rows 0 - 24 (85 total, Query took 0.0049 seconds.` Country table has only one row  for Canada where the numcode column value is 124.

Comment: Please see the third image showing just one row for numcode = "124"

Comment: Your profile introduction is very interesting. You have been programming for such a long time. Glad to be helped by you here

Answer (score 0):

As ypercube mentioned in the comments, if you're only looking for the `printable_name` from the `country` table for a specific `numcode`, then you don't even need to join to the `sku` table, rather you can just filter the `country` table down with a `WHERE` clause like so:

```
SELECT printable_name 
FROM country 
WHERE numcode = '124';
```

Otherwise, if you're trying to get the `printable_name` of each distinct row in `country` where the `numcode` exists in the `c_code` column of the `sku` table, then you can use a **CTE** to get the distinct list of  `c_code` first, then join to it like so:

```
WITH DistinctCCodes AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT c_code
    FROM sku
)

SELECT C.printable_name 
FROM country C
INNER JOIN DistinctCCodes D
    ON C.numcode = D.c_code;
```

Another way to accomplish the same outcome as the above without a CTE, is to just use an inline subquery in the `WHERE` clause (though I find this can be sub-performant sometimes):

```
SELECT printable_name 
FROM country
WHERE numcode IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT c_code
    FROM sku
);
```